# Django & MeMSQL Error when running migrate.py: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2012, 'Error in server handshake')

Tags: mysql, django, migration, handshake, singlestore

I have a Django application with a default MySQL database. I want to move my default Database to MeMSQL.

I set the credentials in `settings.py` to be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': MEMSQL_DB,
        'USER': MEMSQL_USER,
        'PASSWORD': MEMSQL_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': MEMSQL_HOST,
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
```

I try to run `manage.py migrate` to move all models to the new DB, and get this error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2012, 'Error in server handshake')`

If it helps - I tried to test the connection and credentials throughout a workbench (SQL-Pro), and it work successfully. only the `manage.py migrate` give me this error

Comment: check if your new database on MySQL is created and ready to go properly

Comment: Yep. The database is already created.

Comment: if you have install mysqlclient, uninstall it

Comment: First install mysql properly on port 3306. then when creating memsql cluster start from port 3307. i.e. ( host:3307 (master), host:3308 (child aggregator), host:3308 (leaf) )

Comment: I tried to uninstall `mysqlclient` but it didn't help. still getting the same error :(

Comment: add default-auth=mysql_native_password to config

Answer (score 1):

When you connect from the latest version of Django to SingleStore DB, you might receive the following error message:
*django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2012, 'Error in server handshake')*.
To connect to SingleStore DB, you will need to configure the auth_plugin in the OPTIONS field.

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': '{HOST}',
    'NAME': '{DBNAME}',
    'USER': '{USERNAME}',
    'PASSWORD' : '{PASSWORD}',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
      'auth_plugin': 'mysql_native_password'
    }
  }
}
```